# pip3 install virtualenv failed

Tags: python3, pip, virtualenv

I’m using Ubuntu Mate:

Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Kernel: Linux 3.4.39-BPI-M3-Kernel

Architecture: arm

I have installed Python 2.7 & 3.5.2 as well as 3.7.7

Wnen I'm trying to install virtualenv error is returned:

```
pi@bpi-iot-ros-ai:/usr/bin$ pip3 install virtualenv Defaulting to user
installation because normal site-packages is not writeable ERROR:
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py",
line 188, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py",
line 185, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py",
line 278, in run
    session = self.get_default_session(options)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py",
line 83, in get_default_session
    self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))   File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py",
line 100, in _build_session
    index_urls=self._get_index_urls(options),   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py",
line 249, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py",
line 132, in user_agent
    zip(["name", "version", "id"], distro.linux_distribution()),   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py",
line 125, in linux_distribution
    return _distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line
681, in linux_distribution
    self.version(),   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line
741, in version
    self.lsb_release_attr('release'),   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line
903, in lsb_release_attr
    return self._lsb_release_info.get(attribute, '')   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line
556, in __get__
    ret = obj.__dict__[self._fname] = self._f(obj)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line
1014, in _lsb_release_info
    stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=devnull)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr) subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line
10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py",
line 75, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py",
line 114, in main
    return self._main(args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py",
line 226, in _main
    self.handle_pip_version_check(options)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py",
line 155, in handle_pip_version_check
    timeout=min(5, options.timeout)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py",
line 100, in _build_session
    index_urls=self._get_index_urls(options),   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py",
line 249, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py",
line 132, in user_agent
    zip(["name", "version", "id"], distro.linux_distribution()),   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py",
line 125, in linux_distribution
    return _distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line
681, in linux_distribution
    self.version(),   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line
741, in version
    self.lsb_release_attr('release'),   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line
903, in lsb_release_attr
    return self._lsb_release_info.get(attribute, '')   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line
556, in __get__
    ret = obj.__dict__[self._fname] = self._f(obj)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line
1014, in _lsb_release_info
    stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=devnull)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr) subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
pi@bpi-iot-ros-ai:/usr/bin$
```

If I go with --user flag:

```
pi@bpi-iot-ros-ai:/usr/bin$ pip3 install virtualenv --user
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 188, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 185, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    session = self.get_default_session(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 83, in get_default_session
    self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 100, in _build_session
    index_urls=self._get_index_urls(options),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 249, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 132, in user_agent
    zip(["name", "version", "id"], distro.linux_distribution()),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 125, in linux_distribution
    return _distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 681, in linux_distribution
    self.version(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 741, in version
    self.lsb_release_attr('release'),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 903, in lsb_release_attr
    return self._lsb_release_info.get(attribute, '')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 556, in __get__
    ret = obj.__dict__[self._fname] = self._f(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 1014, in _lsb_release_info
    stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=devnull)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 75, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 114, in main
    return self._main(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 226, in _main
    self.handle_pip_version_check(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 155, in handle_pip_version_check
    timeout=min(5, options.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 100, in _build_session
    index_urls=self._get_index_urls(options),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 249, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 132, in user_agent
    zip(["name", "version", "id"], distro.linux_distribution()),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 125, in linux_distribution
    return _distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 681, in linux_distribution
    self.version(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 741, in version
    self.lsb_release_attr('release'),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 903, in lsb_release_attr
    return self._lsb_release_info.get(attribute, '')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 556, in __get__
    ret = obj.__dict__[self._fname] = self._f(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 1014, in _lsb_release_info
    stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=devnull)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
pi@bpi-iot-ros-ai:/usr/bin$
```

How to handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Didier! There was a solution under [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967202/pip-is-showing-error-lsb-release-a-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1/44967506#44967506) which you provided.
So basically I have python 2.7; 3.5 and 3.7. Solution for me was the same as Jerry Isdale had:

> after installing python3.7.3 and changing the symbolic link of python3
>   to point to it, I had this error. Fixed it by changing first line to
>
> **!/usr/bin/python3.5 -Es** the original was almost that... had to add the
>   ".5" only.

So done:

```
$ sudo nano /usr/bin/lsb_release
```

and changed the first line to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5 -Es
```

And `sudo pip3 install virtualenv` went smoothly this time :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `lsb_release` command is missing,
you can install it using `apt`:

```
sudo apt install lsb-release
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't help.It seams I have already installed that: 'pi@bpi-iot-ros-ai:~$ sudo apt install lsb-release
[sudo] password for pi:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
lsb-release is already the newest version (9.20160110ubuntu0.2).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libreadline5
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 54 not upgraded.

' And after that when trying to install virtualenv the same error is returned.

Comment: lsb_release is /usr/bin/lsb_release

Comment: Indeed, so this would mean that /usr/bin/ is not in PATH.

Comment: My guess would be that the virtualenv script changed your working directory, and that `/usr/bin/` is not in your `PATH` (if it was, `lsb_release` would work from anywhere).  
  
What does `echo $PATH` prints ?

Comment: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: Ok, maybe the issue is in the behavior of `lsb_release -a` then. What does the command prints ? `lsb_release -a; echo $?`

Comment: Found a similar issue on Stackoverflow, checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44967506/2320087

Comment: lsb_release -a; echo $? returns:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 25, in <module>
    import lsb_release
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsb_release'
1`

Comment: Ok, so this definitely the same issue as mentionned in the link before.
On Ubuntu 16.06, python3 version is 3.5 by default. `lsb_release` module is installed for python 3.5.
You installed python 3.7 and set it as your default python3 version.
So now when you call `lsb_release`, it does with python 3.7 and can't find the module.

I suppose you want to work in python 3.7, so edit `/usr/bin/lsb_release` script to force it use python 3.5:
first line of `/usr/bin/lsb_release` should be `#!/usr/bin/python3 -Es`, replace it by the following: `#!/usr/bin/python3.5 -Es`

Comment: It work's fine with python 3.5 and you are right that I'd like to use it with python 3.7. How can I force it? I have already tried edit `/usr/bin/lsb_release` to `#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7 -Es` as it is a path to python 3.7.7 but it doesn't work. Only option with 3.5 seems be ok.